# Can not run topcoder arena on Mac

Tags: java

I can not run topcoder arena on my Mac..

When I try to login topcoder from safari, it says Java not found.

So I download the .jnlp....but still can not run

Here is my Java version:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

Here is the error message when running .jnlp from my Mac air:

```
Operation timed out
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:234)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(BasicHttpRequest.java:179)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(BasicHttpRequest.java:67)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.isUpdateAvailable(DownloadEngine.java:977)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.isUpdateAvailable(DownloadEngine.java:882)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(DownloadEngine.java:1619)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(DownloadEngine.java:1578)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(DownloadEngine.java:215)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(LaunchDownload.java:1983)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

In addition, my safari has definitely turned Java on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message doesn't indicate you can't find Java -- it's ConnectionTimedOut, which says you are probably being blocked by a firewall, or the server at topcoder is hosed somehow.